# cacheAsBitmap masks disappear under animated overlay

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I have an application that loads a mask file in runtime (.swf file containing, among other things, a .png with alpha areas) and applies it to a display object once loaded. Naturally, in order to apply the mask properly, both the mask and the masked object need the `cacheAsBitmap = true` to be set.

In the application there are several occasions when an overlay is displayed above masked content, which has a semi-transparent background for "modal" behavior. The background is faded in and out upon show/hide.

On some machines (Mac & PC, more on Mac) the appearance/disappearing of the overlay causes the masked content to disappear from the stage until the browser is resized.

Does anyone know a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Can't say's I do, but at the end of the fade in, you might want to try calling stage.invalidate().

Comment: You might wanna try with this instead of the cacheAsBitmap for the mask: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776187/actionscript3-alpha-masking/1776561#1776561

Comment: [Cay](http://stackoverflow.com/users/126782/cay), could you please put the comment as an answer? It worked out great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because cacheAsBitmap is a bit tricky and unreliable in some scenarios (probably due to the way Flash calculates render areas). Another way of doing alpha masks is with BlendMode.ALPHA... the way to set it up is explained here:
[Actionscript3 alpha masking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776187/actionscript3-alpha-masking/1776561#1776561)

Comment: Works like magic!
A word of warning though: applying a layer with blur filter anywhere above said combination causes the alpha-blended layer to appear in full opacity. I'm guessing it'll happen with any filter applied.