# AS3 - using dynamic Text as a mask

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, text, mask

Pretty sure this is possible. I need to dynamically load and populate a textfield, and in turn then use that text as a mask on a movieclip below it. I have

```
function doMask():void{
    myMc.dynamicTxtField.text = "some text to use as a mask";
    mcToBeMasked.mask = myMc;
}

doMask();
```

What happens is that the ENTIRE Textfield is being used as a mask, NOT just the text it contains.

Comment: Have you tried `mcToBeMasked.mask=myMc.dynamicTxtField`?

Comment: Are there other things inside `myMc`?     The above commend should work. (setting the mask to the text field object itself.)

Comment: For kicks I tested it.  If I dragged a flashPro text field to the stage and used it as a Mask it worked. But if I created a textField solely through code it did not work.  Further investigation needed, but I don't have time at the moment.  @eco_back - are you using a textField created through code?

Comment: You can do this but only if you use embedded fonts and of course if the TextField has no background. You shouldn't need to use cacheAsBitmap in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to use dynamic text as a mask, but you can achieve a similar effect with blend modes. e.g. Multiply the image on top of the dynamic text on a black background.

Comment: Consider making your answer way more useful by adding a code example. Otherwise it's a very low quality answer.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, but I would only be able to write pseudocode. I haven't written AS3 in 4 years, but I still understand how blend modes work.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to both before setting the mask.

```
myMc.dynamicTxtField.cacheAsBitmap = true;
mcToBeMasked.cacheAsBitmap = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using [`BlendMode`][1] as follows (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776187/actionscript3-alpha-masking)):

```
    container.blendMode = BlendMode.LAYER;//parent of toMask and textfield
    toMask.blendMode = BlendMode.NORMAL;//sprite to be masked
    tf.blendMode = BlendMode.ALPHA;//masking textfield
```

[a working example on wonderfl](http://wonderfl.net/c/afdr):

```
package {
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.BlendMode;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    public class FlashTest extends Sprite {
        private var tf:TextField = new TextField();
        private var container:Sprite = new Sprite();
        private var toMask:Sprite = new Sprite();
        private const WIDTH:int = 250;
        private const HEIGHT:int = 150;
        public function FlashTest() {
            graphics.beginFill(0x0000ff);
            graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
            graphics.endFill();       

            addChild(container);     
            tf.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat(null, 15, 0, true);
            tf.text = 'sample text';
            tf.cacheAsBitmap = true;
            container.blendMode = BlendMode.LAYER;
            toMask.blendMode = BlendMode.NORMAL;
            tf.blendMode = BlendMode.ALPHA;
            container.addChild(toMask);
            container.addChild(tf);
            toMask.graphics.beginFill(0x00ff00);
            toMask.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
            toMask.graphics.endFill();
            tf.width = WIDTH;
            tf.height = HEIGHT;
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
        }

        private function onClick(e:MouseEvent = null):void{
            tf.text = 'sample text ' + Math.random();
        }
    }
}
```